# Any example of Airflow FileSensor?

Tags: python, airflow

Whoever can please point me to an example of how to use Airflow FileSensor?
I've googled and haven't found anything yet. Any example would be sufficient. My use case is quite simple:

Wait for a scheduled DAG to drop a file in a path, FileSensor task picks it up, read content and process it.

Comment: See if you can get some insights from [it's unit-tests](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/tests/contrib/sensors/test_file_sensor.py)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor.FileSensor) & [source code](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/contrib/sensors/file_sensor.html#FileSensor):

```
from airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor import FileSensor
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator    import DummyOperator

import datetime
import airflow

# https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.models.BaseOperator
default_args = {
    "depends_on_past" : False,
    "start_date"      : airflow.utils.dates.days_ago( 1 ),
    "retries"         : 1,
    "retry_delay"     : datetime.timedelta( hours= 5 ),
}

with airflow.DAG( "file_sensor_test_v1", default_args= default_args, schedule_interval= "*/5 * * * *", ) as dag:

    start_task  = DummyOperator(  task_id= "start" )
    stop_task   = DummyOperator(  task_id= "stop"  )
    sensor_task = FileSensor( task_id= "my_file_sensor_task", poke_interval= 30, fs_conn_id= <path>, filepath= <file or directory name> )

start_task >> sensor_task >> stop_task
```

Comment: What is "fs_conn_id" and what do I need to substitute here?

Comment: What if the file exists from past job. How can you distinguish from job that wrote the file yesterday vs. today

Comment: That is why we have the version number in the DAG name. Change "file_sensor_test_v1" to "file_sensor_test_v2" and so on as you create new versions.

Comment: fs_conn_id is a connection that you normally define in the UI for the path. Not knowing this can create some confusion. So in the fs_conn_id you define a connection, which might also contain a path.

Answer (score 7):

A simple example of a `FileSensor` task:

```
second_task = FileSensor(
                 task_id="file_sensor_task_id",
                 filepath="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_filepath_task') }}",
                 #fs_conn_id="fs_default" # default one, commented because not needed
                 poke_interval= 20,
                 dag=dag
              )
```

Here I'm passing as `filepath` the returned value of the previous `PythonOperator` `task_id` (named `get_filepath_task`) using `xcom_pull`. 
But it can be a whatever string of a filepath or directory that you are checking the existence.

The `fs_conn_id` parameter is the string name of a connection you have available in the UI Admin/Connections section.

The default value of `fs_conn_id` is `"fs_default"` (you can see it in the code of the `FileSensor` class operator). Check the UI Admin/Connections and you will find it.

You can skip to pass `fs_conn_id` and just pass the parameter `filepath` if you want to check if a file or a directory exists locally.

The `poke_interval` is inherited from `BaseSensorOperator` and it indicates the time in seconds that the job should wait in between each tries. The default value is 60 seconds.